# iterate over bundled properties in boost graph in a direct way

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using the Boost graph library exploiting the following definitions

```
template <typename Vertex>
using graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,
                                    boost::vecS,
                                    boost::bidirectionalS,
                                    Vertex>

template <typename Vertex>
using vertex = typename graph<Vertex>::vertex_descriptor;
```

where the template parameter `Vertex` is employed to use the BGL with bundled properties.

I'm not that confident with boost at the moment and I'd like to understand if is there a way to get the `begin()` and `end()` iterators of the "bundled property list".
In other words, let's assume I have this struct

```
struct City
{
  string name;
  int population;
  vector<int> zipcodes;
};
```

and I want to use it as template parameter for my graph. I know I can iterate over vertexes like this
(assuming `g` is my adjacency list)

```
for(auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))
{
      auto v = g[*vd];
      // do something with v
}
```

yet I'd like to do this

```
for(auto & v : some_iterator)
   // v is a city ...
```

is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Please in the future just edit your existing question! By deleting the other you threw away my answer text. And the question is fundamentally unchanged (though I see the improvement)

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted [my code from your now-deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925611/begin-and-end-iterators-for-boost-graph-with-custom-vertex) to the more specific example. By now you already realize you are NOT in fact iterating vertices, but their bundles.

I suggest you use a transforming/indirected iterator adaptor. The easiest way I can think of is to use Boost Range Adaptors, specifically using `transformed`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb11c7c0a1f2ec50)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
using boost::adaptors::transformed;

template <typename Vertex> struct Wrapper {
    using graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS,
                                        boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex>;

    using vertex = typename graph::vertex_descriptor;

    auto bundles() {
        auto accessor = [map = get(boost::vertex_bundle, _g)](vertex v) -> auto& {
            return map[v];
        };
        return vertices(_g) | transformed(accessor);
    }

    auto bundles() const {
        auto accessor = [map = get(boost::vertex_bundle, _g)](vertex v) -> auto& {
            return map[v];
        };
        return vertices(_g) | transformed(accessor);
    }

  private:
    graph _g {5};
};

struct City {
    std::string      name;
    int              population;
    std::vector<int> zipcodes;
};

static int id_gen = 0;
struct Sample2 { int id = ++id_gen; };

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    Wrapper<City> demo;

    for (City& c : demo.bundles()) {
        c.name       = "name " + std::to_string(rand() % 100);
        c.population = rand() % 128 * 190'000;
        c.zipcodes   = {1234, 2345};
    }

    auto const& const_ref = demo;
    for (City const& c : const_ref.bundles()) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(c.name) << ", population " << c.population << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"name 83", population 13300000
"name 77", population 21850000
"name 93", population 24130000
"name 86", population 20520000
"name 49", population 14630000
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. What if `City` is not copyable nor movable ?

Comment: Then you cannot - by definition - use it as the bundle type, because it doesn't meet de storage requirements [documented](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html#:~:text=The%20types%20of%20all%20property%20values%20must%20be%20Copy%20Constructible%2C%20Assignable%2C%20and%20Default%20Constructible.). Of course you can maybe work around it with a wrapper (optional<>, some smart pointer or something) but it will generally be easier to work with the library if you avoid that

Comment: Thanks again. Just one last question: where are bundled properties stored ? What I don't get is why do I need to "pack" them in a new structure using adaptors. I was looking for a way to get iterators from data structured employed by the BGL to store them, but my understanding of the library is not good enough

Comment: Hmm you can already store iterators. Keep in mind iterator invalidation rules though. _"why do I need to "pack" them in a new structure using adaptors"_ - that sounds confused. Where do you have the properties /now/? Also, "adaptors" probably refer to property maps. They are NOT used to store ("pack") properties somewhere else. Instead, they are generalized _procedural_ ways to retrieve/update properties stored in arbitrary locations (given descriptors).

Comment: I don't understand your answer, but I'm pretty sure I didn't ask a clear question. What I'd like to know is if is there a way to get an iterator from the container the bundled properties are stored in. Basically I don't get where the bundled properties are hence I don't know how to return their iterators (and of course I don't want to return `vertices(g).first` as `begin()` or `vertices(g).second` as `end()` because this doesn't return the iterator to the bundled vertex but to its vertex descriptor). Thanks again, I appreciate your help

Comment: _"to get an iterator from the container the bundled properties are stored in"_ - that's implementation detail. You *can* store your properties in your own containers (in fact, you can store your [entire graph]() in your own datastructures, using the power of generic concepts). The trade-off is that it will be your job to keep them in sync with the graph and pass property maps for them to all algorithms that need the properties.

Comment: But to respond to the simpler _"I don't want to return vertices(g).first as begin() or vertices(g).second as end()"_ note that my answer is exactly what you want. It is **NOT** returning `vertices(g).begin()`. Instead, returns an `transformed_range<Lambda, std::pair<VertexIterator> >` with the projection to the bundle in the lambda. Does it make it clearer when I write the old-fashioned iterator loops instead of the tanged-for: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fb14faffc439b14 ?

Comment: yes, the last part is what I was actually looking for since I can now return bundles().begin() and bundles().end() in my wrapper's overloads. I missed that info  at the begining.  Thanks again !